# How can I detect collisions between Tilemap Colliders and 2D box colliders in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection

I've run into a bit of a problem in my developing of a Unity2D game.

I'm trying to have bullets be destroyed when they hit a part of a tile map I created. When a bullet and a tile map collide, the "OnCollisionEnter2D()" function doesn't read the collision. It does read the collision between sprites and other sprites however. But not between a sprite and a tile map.

I've checked and both objects have the appropriate collider components (Box Collider 2D and Tilemap Collider 2D) and they also have their scripts attached.

Can somebody suggest a solution of tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, Maiko vd Veen.

Comment: Give us a photo of both object settings in the inspector so we can see what is going on. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your bullet need a rigidbody2D to trigger a collision between colliders.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the bullet collider is marked as a trigger? In that case, use [`OnTriggerEnter2D()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html).